# Find the slope of the tangent line to the curve given parametrically

Tags: calculus, parametric

The parametric curves I'm working with are:

$ x=t^2-t$ and $y=\sqrt{t+2}$

I need to find the slope of the tangent at t = 2

I found the derivative wrt t for both:

$ dx/dt = 2t-1$, $dy/dt={1\over 2\sqrt{t+2}}$

The answer I got is:

$y={\sqrt{3}\over 2}x +2-\sqrt{3}$

Can someone please verify if my answer is right?

Comment: You can check your answer using graphing software: on Desmos, $(t^2 - t, \sqrt{t+2})$ gives you the parametric curve for $a ≤ t ≤ b$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not correct. Your derivatives wrt $t$ are correct, so $\frac{dy}{dx} |_{t=2} = \frac{1/(2 \sqrt{2+2})}{2(2) - 1} = \frac{1}{12}$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = (t^{2} - t,\sqrt{t+2})$. Then the tangent vector at $t = 2$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
\gamma'(t) = \left(2t - 1,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+2}}\right) \Rightarrow \gamma'(2) = \left(3,\frac{1}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Consequently, the tangent line at $(2,2)$ can be described as:
\begin{align*}
s(t) & = (2,2) + t\gamma'(2)\\\\
& = (2,2) + t\left(3,\frac{1}{4}\right)\\\\
& = \left(2 + 3t, 2 + \frac{t}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Eliminating the parameter $t$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{x-2}{3} = 4(y-2) & \Longleftrightarrow 12y - x - 4 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y = \frac{x}{12} - \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Therefore the slope of the tangent line is given by $1/12$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This possibly uses language slightly more technical than the OP knows about.